# Performing an operation on multiple columns in a list of data

Tags: r, list, lapply

Suppose I have the following data frames in a list:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = runif(3), y = runif(3))
df2 <- data.frame(x = runif(3), y = runif(3))
df.list <- list(df1, df2)
```

Now suppose I want to add column x and y to get column z
I know to do this in a dataframe with mutate is as easy as:

```
dplyr::mutate(lapply(df.list, z = x + y))
```

How do I perform operations on multiple columns in a list using lapply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `transform` with `lapply`

```
lapply(df.list, transform, z= x+y)
```

If we need to do this for multiple columns,

```
lapply(df.list, transform, z= x+y, w= x*y)
```

---

Another option would be using `library(purr)` (from the authors of `dplyr`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df.list %>% 
      map(mutate, z=x+y, w= z*y)
```