# How to use lapply and paste on multiple dataframes in a list

Tags: r, lapply, paste

I can't combine the use of lapply and paste to combine two columns for multiple dataframes contained within a list. I've looked through multiple sources, but can't find the answer.

This answer
[Apply paste over a list of vectors to get a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723493/apply-paste-over-a-list-of-vectors-to-get-a-list-of-strings) is about combining rows within lists, not combining columns to obtain a vector.

This answer explains how to select columns but not paste them together [using lapply on a list of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985192/using-lapply-on-a-list-of-dataframes)

This page explains how to access columns in lists, but not how to combine them together https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family

This answer is the closest, but I can't use transform on text [Performing an operation on multiple columns in a list of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797821/performing-an-operation-on-multiple-columns-in-a-list-of-data)

The code below is an example which successfully creates the output, but does not use lapply. I will be applying this function over many different dataframes, so need to use lapply. Presumably I could use a for i loop, but lapply is probably cleaner. I need to use lapply, rather than sapply, as the dataframes will have different lengths.

I want to replace the three lines that start output1, output2 and output with an lapply function that will work across the two dataframes in this example. I think it should be something like

```
output <-lapply(mylist, paste($Artist,$Song))
```

But that doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

```
Artist <- c("Drake", "Ed Sheeran", "Bruno Mars", "Camilla Cabello", "BlocBoy")    
Song <- c("Gods Plan", "Perfect", "Finesse", "Havana", "Look Alive")
Current <- data.frame(cbind(Artist,Song))
Artist <- c("Gucci Mane", "Migos", "Daft Punk", "Chainsmokers")
Song <- c("Black Beatles", "Bad and Boujee", "Starboy", "Closer")
Past <- data.frame(cbind(Artist,Song))

mylist <- list(Current,Past)

output1  <- paste(mylist[[1]]$Artist,mylist[[1]]$Song)
output2  <- paste(mylist[[2]]$Artist,mylist[[2]]$Song)
output <-list(output1,output2)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're going for:

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) paste(x$Artist, x$Song, sep=" "))
```

We just need to define the little anonymous function to concatenate the columns.

```
[[1]]
[1] "Drake Gods Plan"        "Ed Sheeran Perfect"     "Bruno Mars Finesse"    
[4] "Camilla Cabello Havana" "BlocBoy Look Alive"    

[[2]]
[1] "Gucci Mane Black Beatles" "Migos Bad and Boujee"    
[3] "Daft Punk Starboy"        "Chainsmokers Closer"
```

Comment: or `lapply(mylist, do.call, what = paste)`

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `purrr::map` from the `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

map(list(Current, Past), ~ paste(.$Artist, .$Song))

[[1]]
[1] "Drake Gods Plan"        "Ed Sheeran Perfect"     "Bruno Mars Finesse"    
[4] "Camilla Cabello Havana" "BlocBoy Look Alive"    

[[2]]
[1] "Gucci Mane Black Beatles" "Migos Bad and Boujee"     "Daft Punk Starboy"       
[4] "Chainsmokers Closer"
```